# How to put url files into an array list in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have a system where I store url files in each row in my mysql database. I want to use this data to put it into an array and use it in a javascript function. For example:

```
var files_list = "https://example.com/file1.docx,https://example.com/file2.docx,https://example.com/file3.docx,"; //value obtained via ajax

var links = [files_list];
```

This shows error, so how can I separate each url and get from this:

```
var links = ["https://example.com/file1.docx,https://example.com/file2.docx,https://example.com/file3.docx,"];
```

To this:

```
var links = ["https://example.com/file1.docx","https://example.com/file2.docx","https://example.com/file3.docx",];
```

I would like some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` string function. Something like `files_list.split(",")`.

> The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Example:

```
var files_list = "https://example.com/file1.docx,https://example.com/file2.docx,https://example.com/file3.docx,"; //value obtained via ajax

var links = files_list.split(",");

console.log(links); // Will print this ["https://example.com/file1.docx", "https://example.com/file2.docx", "https://example.com/file3.docx", ""]
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 3):

you need to split the string

```
links = files_list.split(',')
```